# What does Middle English “yreyn” mean?

Tags: middle-english

What does Middle English “yreyn” mean?

[Wycliffe's Bible](https://www.originalbibles.com/wycliffe-bible-new-testament-1400-pdf/)

Isaiah.59:5

[Studylight:](https://www.studylight.org/desk/index.cgi?sr=0&old_q=yreyn&search_form_type=general&q1=Isaiah%2059%3A5&s=0&t1=en_wyc&ns=0)

"Thei han broke eiren of snakis, and maden webbis of an yreyn; he that etith of the eiren of hem, schal die, and that that is nurschid, ether brouyt forth, schal breke out in to a cocatrice."

King James Bible:

"They hatch cockatrice' eggs, and weave the spider's web: he that eateth of their eggs dieth, and that which is crushed breaketh out into a viper."

Comment: The Middle English dictinoary is really good, you should start there. [They give lots of alternate spellings for 'arain' including the Wycliffe bible one](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED2072/track?counter=1&search_id=1204296) (click on 'Show 19 quotations).

Comment: With all these questions, why do you not trust the translation you give?

Comment: @Mitch I didn't know this "arain" word

Comment: @AndrewLeach I trust, but I want to know a literal meaning.

Comment: @AnatoliySydorov I didn't know it either. I just searched for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *OED* lists *yreyn* as a spelling of *arain*, an obsolete word meaning *spider*.

Comment: Compare French "araignée"